# Ability to use border-top CSS to create a line where the left and right is 2px height but middle is 5px height

Tags: html, css

Trying to recreate this https://ibb.co/mJgsR44 with CSS / border-top

The sides would be equal width and the middle would be a max width of 300px or similar and responsive so on mobile it can adapt.

If i use border-top: 2p solid #c3b69e it will make it one height of course. Is there a way to use some other CSS properties to achieve this in the image?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You seem to already have a solution to your problem -- are you asking for other ways the same solution could be achieved? If so, why? Does your solution have some sort of caveat or downside?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
align-items:center;
}
.border-1{
border-bottom:2px solid gold;
width:30%;

}
.border-2{
border-bottom:5px solid gold;
width:40%;

}

.border-3{
border-bottom:2px solid gold;
width:30%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class=main>
<div class=border-1>
</div>
<div class=border-2>
</div>
<div class=border-3>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.